# achieve same layout on android & iOS Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

i'm creating an ios,android app using titanium so i positioning my ui view on specific percentage from screen size using `platformWidth` and `platformHeight` multiplied by a number 
e.g. `0.5*platformHeight` for the middle of the screen and every thing work on all iOS devices sizes.
but on android devices this value became too large

```
Note i m using "dp" as a default unit
```

so any idea on how to achieve same layout in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use percentage as value of position properties. ex `top : '40%'`. This percentage is calculated wrt parent. And if you don't specify any position by default the view will be positioned in centre of the parent unless, parent is a  vertical or horizontal layout.

Also are you specifying the default unit as below?

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit">dp</property>
```

If this is the case then here's what might be happening. Say the device height is 800px. Halving it give 400 px. This is the value you are expecting. But when you assign this value again to the view it is converted to DP. So, it turns out to be 400 x device density, which will be greater than 400 for sure. To overcome this you might have to assign the property something like `top: 0.5*platformHeight+'px'`. I'm not sure if this trick will work as I do not have the setup to test it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Titanium documentation on `platformHeight`:

> Absolute height of the display in relation to UI orientation. Measured in platform-specific units; pixels on Android and density-independent pixels (dip) on iOS.

Because Titanium uses pixels, you also need to use pixels on Android, or the values will be too large for most phones. dp are based on the density of the screen, so 100 dp are somewhat the same in physical size on every phone.

More about that can be read here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thanks tknell but if i position an element with "100dp" from to of the screen it will look the same on both platform and i m looking from achieve same thing thing using percentage from the screen sizes so you mean this couldn't be done on android bcuz i m want my item to look like same as a design PSDs for that i m using percentage

Comment: Yes, but if Titanium gives you pixel values with platformHeight on Android, if you don't use them as pixels, but as dp, platformHeight*0.5 won't be the half size of the screen, but something different based on the screen size and density.

Answer (score 0):

Read a detailed answered by @Malcolm agreed by many experts.He has been upvoted multiple times for this answer

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148337/how-to-achieve-same-layout-for-android-and-iphone-using-titanium

Thanks